# Setup fail2ban with apf

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, fail2ban

Along with BFD we have recently installed fail2ban on our server, it is CentOS and it uses APF to block IPs.

I have hunted online on how to get the two to work however when an IP is blocked by fail2ban it doesn't show up in APF.

I have manually changed the actionban in iptables-multiport.conf to point to apd instead of iptables but it still doesn't work.

jail.local

```
[exim]

enabled = true
filter  = exim
logpath = /var/log/exim/mainlog
action  = iptables-multiport[name=exim,port="25,465,587"]
       sendmail-whois[name=exim, dest=email@email.com, sender=email@email.com, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
#action = apf[name=eximfail2ban]
#        sendmail-whois[name=exim, dest=email@email.com, sender=email@email.com, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What's in the log for fail2ban at startup?

Comment: @sebix fail2ban is loading fine as it is told to email in startup and I get emails for exim "Hi,

The jail dovecot has been started successfully.

Regards,

Fail2Ban
"

Answer (score 2):

I have finally solved this, runnning the commands manually from the configuration showed that it needed the full path to APF.

Once this was added it started to work!